# Apply filter and sorting same time firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase json tree is like

```
{
"-KZVOY6qU29fJlRSwRNo" : {
    "fedStateDetails" : "Fasted",
    "targetkcal" : 596,
    "timestamp" : 1.482307285673975E9,
    "userid" : "816",
    "workout_id" : "123"
  },
  "-KZVSmeW94XetROs0nsN" : {
    "fedStateDetails" : "Fasted",
    "targetkcal" : 1874,
    "timestamp" : 1.482308270356936E9,
    "userid" : "47",
    "workout_id" : "129"
  },
  "-KZWGdx-j1q7J37x0wck" : {
    "fedStateDetails" : "Fasted",
    "targetkcal" : 0,
    "timestamp" : 1.482321866382767E9,
    "userid" : "47",
    "workout_id" : "40"
  }
}
```

So all I need is to get those users where "userid" is 47 and "timestamp" is between given range, My code looks like below.

```
let startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - 10800.0
        let endTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        self.dbRef.child(FireBaseTable.workOutInfoTable)
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
            .queryStarting(atValue: startTime, childKey: "timestamp")
            .queryEnding(atValue: endTime, childKey: "timestamp")
            .queryEqual(toValue: "47")
            .observe(.value) { (snapshot1 :FIRDataSnapshot?) in
            if let value : Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = snapshot1?.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            {
                print("*********")
                print(value)
            }
        }
```

But I can't apply two order by together. Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no its not possible to add 2 orders at a same time in firebase ... after getting data you have to order it by some other way

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Yes, i know that but how to get expected results? any suggestion? it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the majority of the times you need to access these items, it'll be per user, you can change your data model:

```
{
"user816": {
  "-KZVOY6qU29fJlRSwRNo" : {
    "fedStateDetails" : "Fasted",
    "targetkcal" : 596,
    "timestamp" : 1.482307285673975E9,
    "workout_id" : "123"
  }
},
"user47": {
  "-KZVSmeW94XetROs0nsN" : {
    "fedStateDetails" : "Fasted",
    "targetkcal" : 1874,
    "timestamp" : 1.482308270356936E9,
    "workout_id" : "129"
  },
  "-KZWGdx-j1q7J37x0wck" : {
    "fedStateDetails" : "Fasted",
    "targetkcal" : 0,
    "timestamp" : 1.482321866382767E9,
    "workout_id" : "40"
  }
}
}
```

Now you can access the data for a specific user with `child()` and then use `queryOrder(byChild:"timestamp")` to order them by timestamp.

I recommend:

- reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)
- studying my answer [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)